# In Aviation terms, what is a Ground Stop?

Tags: air-travel, airports, terminology

This week Boston Logan Airport had a Ground Stop issued, and with the network outages across America, some airlines had them too. What is one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [ground stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_stop) is a ban of all aircraft taking off or landing at an airport.

This could be due to a variety of reasons, but is primarily for safety - weather could be an issue (e.g. thunderstorms), or there could be a security alert on the ground, or concern about something that may be on board a plane.

It's usually issued by the FAA, but could be issued by an individual airport as well.

Flights already inbound may be directed to other cities to land there instead.

Comment: Ground stop also includes holding aircraft at other airports that are bound for the affected airport.  For example, if severe storms shut down ORD, in addition to halting planes on the ground at ORD, planes elsewhere that are scheduled to fly to ORD will be held at their origination airport.